# How to retain namespaces in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have an xml file like this

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <n xmlns="http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcd.com/bgft">
         <document>
            <docbody>
                ......
                ......
                ......
            </docbody>
          </document>
       </n>
     </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

i want to render that xml and copy that  part using xslt under a new element . but the problem is i can not render that xml with those name spaces in  element. so i have to remove those namespaces through xslt but i need those name spaces in my output xml. My output xml should be like that.

```
<m>
  <n>
    <o>
      <n xmlns="http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcd.com/bgft">
          <abc>
              <document>
                <docbody>
                    ......
                    ......
                    ......
                </docbody>
              </document>
           </abc>
         </n>
      </o>
    </n>
</m>
```

here  is a new element

how can i pass through  element removing namespaces and copy  amd retain namespaces of  in final output? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to remove and then restore the namespaces. If you simply copy the child nodes of the `c` element while transforming it to a `o` element you are done:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <o>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </o>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <m>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </m>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <n>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </n>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. My output is basically a predefined format. i need to copy that <document> element. My main problem is retaining the mnamespaces of <n> and mach that output format. My question was i am able to copy that <document> element but for that i have to remove the namespaces. But according to output format i nood to include those namespaces. Please tell me how can i retain those namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "adding" or "removing" of any namespaces here, you're simply translating element names `a`, `b`, and `c` (in no namespace) to `m`, `n` and `o` (also in no namespace) and adding an `abc` element in the `http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer` namespace between the original `{http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer}n` element and its children.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:play="http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer"
                exclude-result-prefixes="play">

  <!-- identity template - copy everything as-is unless we say otherwise -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <m><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></m>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <n><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></n>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <o><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></o>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the original <n xmlns="http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer"> element.
       We have to use a prefix for this because no prefix always means no
       namespace in XPath -->
  <xsl:template match="play:n">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- preserve the xsi:schemaLocation attribute -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <!-- insert an abc element in the right namespace -->
      <abc xmlns="http://www.abcd.com/play/soccer">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </abc>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. My output is basically a predefined format. i need to copy that <document> element. My main problem is retaining the mnamespaces of <n> and mach that output format. My question was i am able to copy that <document> element but for that i have to remove the namespaces. But according to output format i nood to include those namespaces. Please tell me how can i retain those namespaces.

Comment: @SubhadipBanerjee I still don't understand what you mean about "adding" and "removing" namespaces. For the input and output XMLs in the question this stylesheet will do exactly what you've asked for, if this is not what you need then please create another question with more realistic examples of your true inputs and outputs and the XSLT you have tried so far.